# Filter rows in Python with duplicate condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a table:

```
     A       B     C     D     E     T
    ----    ----  ---   ---   ---   --- 
0    2      3      5     10    21    5
1    4      7      6      8    30   11
```

I want to be able to drop rows which do not have at least one matching value from any of the columns A-E with the value in column T for that record.
So for example, in row 0 the value 5 in column C matches with the 5 in Column T, so we keep that row. In row 1, the value 11 in Column T does not match with any of the values in columns A-E, so we drop that record.  What's the best way to do this?

Comment: How have you represented the rows in python? Have you read them into a list, or a dict?

Comment: This table is a DataFrame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: Using `eq`(==) and `sum`with axis=1, if that is more than 1 it should be some columns repeat the columns T 's value

```
df[df.eq(df['T'],0).sum(1).gt(1)]
Out[84]: 
   A  B  C   D   E  T
0  2  3  5  10  21  5
```

Comment: This doesn't account for the uniqueness of column T. It will returns rows with duplicates in **any** column.

Comment: Someone please help

Comment: @gedman: just to be clear, although I can't speak for max, the complaint that I had about the original version (and the reason I downvoted) no longer applies.